# How would you implement ant-style patternsets in python to select groups of files?

Tags: python, file, ant

Ant has a nice way to select groups of files, most handily using ** to indicate a directory tree. E.g.

```
**/CVS/*            # All files immediately under a CVS directory.
mydir/mysubdir/**   # All files recursively under mysubdir
```

More examples can be seen here:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html

How would you implement this in python, so that you could do something like:

```
files = get_files("**/CVS/*")
for file in files:
    print file

=>
CVS/Repository
mydir/mysubdir/CVS/Entries
mydir/mysubdir/foo/bar/CVS/Entries
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you come across a `**`, you're going to have to recurse through the whole directory structure, so I think at that point, the easiest method is to iterate through the directory with os.walk, construct a path, and then check if it matches the pattern.  You can probably convert to a regex by something like:

```
def glob_to_regex(pat, dirsep=os.sep):
    dirsep = re.escape(dirsep)
    print re.escape(pat)
    regex = (re.escape(pat).replace("\\*\\*"+dirsep,".*")
                           .replace("\\*\\*",".*")
                           .replace("\\*","[^%s]*" % dirsep)
                           .replace("\\?","[^%s]" % dirsep))
    return re.compile(regex+"$")
```

(Though note that this isn't that fully featured - it doesn't support `[a-z]` style glob patterns for instance, though this could probably be added).  (The first `\*\*/` match is to cover cases like `\*\*/CVS` matching `./CVS`, as well as having just `\*\*` to match at the tail.)

However, obviously you don't want to recurse through everything below the current dir when not processing a `**` pattern, so I think you'll need a two-phase approach.  I haven't tried implementing the below, and there are probably a few corner cases, but I think it should work:

1. Split the pattern on your directory seperator.  ie `pat.split('/') -> ['**','CVS','*']`
2. Recurse through the directories, and look at the relevant part of the pattern for this level.  ie. `n levels deep -> look at pat[n]`.
3. If `pat[n] == '**'` switch to the above strategy:

   - Reconstruct the pattern with `dirsep.join(pat[n:])`
   - Convert to a regex with `glob\_to\_regex()`
   - Recursively `os.walk` through the current directory, building up the path relative to the level you started at.  If the path matches the regex, yield it.
4. If pat doesn't match `"**"`, and it is the last element in the pattern, then yield all files/dirs matching `glob.glob(os.path.join(curpath,pat[n]))`
5. If pat doesn't match `"**"`, and it is NOT the last element in the pattern, then for each directory, check if it matches (with glob) `pat[n]`.  If so, recurse down through it, incrementing depth (so it will look at `pat[n+1]`)

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, this is quite a long time after your OP. I have just released a Python package which does exactly this - it's called Formic and it's available at the [PyPI Cheeseshop](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/formic). With Formic, your problem is solved with:

```
import formic
fileset = formic.FileSet(include="**/CVS/*", default_excludes=False)
for file_name in fileset.qualified_files():
    print file_name
```

There is one slight complexity: default_excludes. Formic, just like Ant, excludes CVS directories by default (as for the most part collecting files from them for a build is dangerous), the default answer to the question would result in no files. Setting default_excludes=False disables this behaviour.

Comment: fantastically simple library to use. Thanks Andrew. I had to use `easy_install` instead of `pip` to get this to install properly in Python 2.7.6 in a `virtualenv`. Otherwise works like a charm. Saved me a huge amount of work (and let me delete about 50 lines of code).

Answer (score 2):

`os.walk` is your friend. Look at the example in the Python manual 
(https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) and try to build something from that.

To match "`**/CVS/*`" against a file name you get, you can do something like this:

```
def match(pattern, filename):
    if pattern.startswith("**"):
        return fnmatch.fnmatch(file, pattern[1:])
    else:
        return fnmatch.fnmatch(file, pattern)
```

In `fnmatch.fnmatch`, "*" matches anything (including slashes).

Comment: That's fine for enumerating a tree of files. The problem would be determining whether a particular file matches the given search pattern. E.g. Does '/mydir/CVS/Entries' match the given '**/CVS/*' pattern?

Comment: Yes, but once you've started walking, matching files is simply a matter of translating the fileset expression into a suitable regular expression and filtering the results.

Answer (score 1):

There's an implementation in the 'waf' build system source code.
http://code.google.com/p/waf/source/browse/trunk/waflib/Node.py?r=10755#471
May be this should be wrapped up in a library of its own?

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Your best bet is, as has already been suggested, to work with 'os.walk'. Or, write wrappers around '[glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html)' and '[fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html)' modules, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

[os.walk](http://www.python.org/doc/2.6/library/os.html#os.walk) is your best bet for this.  I did the example below with .svn because I had that handy, and it worked great:

```
import re

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk("."):
    if re.search(r'\.svn$', dirpath):
        for file in filenames:
            print file
```